# They used to sing together

Tags: knowledge, cipher

Who are they?  They used to sing together.

```
16 8 7 7 39 and 6 1 68
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The singing duo are:

> [SONNY AND CHER](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonny_%26_Cher)

> The numbers represent the elements of the [periodic table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) via their atomic numbers in their abbreviated forms: S,O,N,N,Y and C,H,ER.
>  Or
>  SULPHUR, OXYGEN, NITROGEN, NITROGEN, [YTTRIUM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium), and CARBON, HYDROGEN, [ERBIUM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbium).

Comment: I'm proud of myself. My first thought was those two. I guess all those years of memorizing the periodic table paid off, even if I can't actually remember it

Comment: My first thought was Roman numerals, then Greek, then A1Z26 then it was only because I recently realised you can make a cipher using the elements when I was trying to solve a puzzle on here and failed! that the periodic table struck me as a possibility otherwise it certainly would have been a lot tougher.